# Open a Sequence of Activities - Android

Tags: android, android-activity, sequence, display

> I am new to android programming. in my app a have the first activity that >displays a menu. After that I have another that has a list of scientists. but >I would like to click on one of the scientists and open another activity that >would diplay informtion about them.
>
> The problme is, when I try to open the third activity after opening the >activity with the list of scientists the app goes blank and back to the menu >activity and does not display the activity with information about about the >scientist.
>
> Activity one --> activity 2 --> activity 3
>
> I dont know what I am doing wrong.

```
>Thanks for helping me.


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Alan Turing -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/alanturing4" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/OpcoesAlanTuring"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="#80cbc4"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:onClick="OpenTuringOptions"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Alan Turing"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- Albert Einstein -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/einstein3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="#9ccc65"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:onClick="OptionsAlanTuring"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Albert Einstein"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- Dennis Ritchie -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/dennisritchie" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="#fff59d"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Dennis Ritchie"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- Elon Musk -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/elonmusk" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="#b71c1c"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Elon Musk"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- Leonardo da Vinci -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/leonardodavinci" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="#ffeb3b"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Leonardo da Vinci"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- Linus Torvalds -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/linustorvalds" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="#ff5722"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Linus Torvalds"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- Marie Curie -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/isaacnewton" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="#7e57c2"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Isaac Newton"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- René Descartes -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/descartes" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="#f48fb1"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="René Descartes"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- Stephen Hawking -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/stephen2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="#aed581"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Stephen Hawking"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- Tim Berners Lee -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/timbernerslle" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="#26a69a"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Tim Berners-Lee"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>


public class explore extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_explore);
    }

    public void OpenTuringOptions(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, opcoesalanturing.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }

}
```

Comment: add activity 2 and 3 code

Comment: no you didnt understand. those are created. when from activity 2 i want to open activity three the app goes back to activity one

Comment: no add your activity 2 and 3 code here so we can look for the issue

Comment: how many activities can I open one after each other. Do I have to close one activity after entering the other?

Comment: java code not xml

Comment: that is all the java code I have. it is at the bottom

Comment: I just want to open the third activity

Comment: did you create opcoesalanturing activity ?

Comment: yes. i included the xml of that activity

Comment: please add the java code

Comment: I did that. It is what is at the bottom of the post. what i have is the intent to open the third activity

Comment: You want from class explore to opcoesalanturing?